How to submit Spark jobs from Java app running on K8s cluster?
I have a local Kubernetes cluster (rancher desktop) with Spark installed on it from Bitnami helm chart (1 master and 2 worked nodes).
On the same Kubernetes cluster I have a Java application (Quarkus) exposing one REST GET endpoint and I want a Spark job to be submitted when I invoke this endpoint. Ultimately I want to submit many jobs pretty often, so performance aspect of those submittions is important here.
Spark provides SparkLauncher class in its core package for this in Java, which should be used to submit jobs.
SparkLauncher class requires "sparkHome" and "master" properties set to submit a job.
My two questions are:

How should I configure my "sparkHome" and "master" in this scenario to submit jobs optimally (performance wise)?
Where should I keep JARs with my custom Spark jobs to be quickly visible by Spark cluster? JARs might be around 2GB in size.

Currently I have Spark "bin" and "jars" directories copied to "Resources" directory of my Java app and I try to use SparkLauncher like this:
new SparkLauncher()
                .setSparkHome("src/main/resources/spark")
                .setDeployMode("cluster")
                .setMaster("spark://my-spark.default.svc.cluster.local:7077")
                .setAppResource("src/main/resources/spark-examples_2.13-3.5.1.jar")
                .setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi")
                .startApplication(this);

It works when I execute code from Intellij IDEA, but fails on K8s cluster with error:

"java.io.IOException","message":"Cannot run program
"src/main/resources/spark/bin/spark-submit": error=2, No such file
or directory"


Spark uses the SPARK_HOME variable to find the necessary configurations, libraries and executables, by default if you haven't changed it is the /spark folder, but to be on the safe side I suggest you go into the master contrainer and run echo $SPARK_HOME.
in the setMaster you should indicate address and port of the spark master in your kubernetes cluster,
for jars I recommend you to stor them in an s3 bucket, it is the most common solution

Thanks for the answer and just to be sure:


SPARK_HOME value that I set in SparkLauncher class is send to my Spark master node and then master tries to find necessary configurations under this path, correct? So it has to be reachable from my master perspective, but not from my Java app perspective?


When I store JARs in S3 bucket they have to be downloaded every time I submit a job, correct? I was wondering if maybe I should place my job JARs inside all Spark nodes (master and every worker) to be accessible faster (no communication with S3). Is is a bad idea?



exactly for question 1, for question number 2 it depends, you have to consider jar size, frequency of usage, ecc. the more memory you have occupied on nodes the less memory spark can use for if you need to persist data on disk.

Thank you very much! Java app couldn't connect to master but it works now. When executing SparkPi im getting error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcEndpointVerifier$CheckExistence; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5378738997755484868, local class serialVersionUID = 7789290765573734431","threadName":"launcher-proc-2" but its not related to original question, so I'll try to find solution online I guess.

afjcjsbx you said "exactly for question 1" in your previous comment, but unfortunately it is not true. My Java app looks for "spark-submit" script under SPARK_HOME location before it is send to Spark master node, so currently I must have my Spark scripts and jars packaged with my Java app for this to work.

The official documentation says that the path to specify in the setSparkHome function is the path where Spark is installed on the worker nodes
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkConf.setSparkHome.html

I understand, so it might be isleading because in my case it definitely looks for spark on the "source" node (which is my Java app from which im sending the submit) and not the worker node.

you are right, sorry but I got confused with the documentation, I got the setSparkHome function from the SparkConf class rather than the SparkLauncher class, actually reading online SparkLauncher.setSparkHome() is used to set spark home which is used internally to call spark submit.
